# Generating source package with CPack on Windows

Tags: cmake, cpack

On OS X and Linux, I successfully used CMake/CPack to generate source package with `make package_source`.

However, on Windows, I couldn't find a equivalent target after generating the Visual Studio project files ("Visual Studio 12 2013" to be exact).

There is a `PACKAGE.vcxproj` which can generate a binary package. But it seems there is no project file for generating source package.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps someone viewing this can shed some light on how cpack is or why it is not integrated into VS when ctest and install targets are - See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59645959/1569204

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, but it is backlogged, as nobody was working on it:
https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13058

Possible workaround: If you can, try to re-configure your project with NMAKE, then it should work.