# How do you run cpack from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cpack

I am porting some packages from Linux to windows and I've found that visual studio has quite good integration with cmake. 
I am able to configure and build the project using cmake but ***I cannot figure out how to run cpack to create the installation package***.

This question - [How to create an installer with CMake + CPack + NSIS on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144181/how-to-create-an-installer-with-cmake-cpack-nsis-on-windows) - suggests that a *PACKAGE.vcxproj* file should be created by the build. It is but there doesn't appear to be anyway to build/run it from inside visual studio

It seems a strange oversight as:

- cmake integration is very good
- ctest tests can be run via the tests menu
- the install target can be run via the build menu
  but there is no menu option to create packages with cpack.

Note I am trying to create ZIP or TGZ package and don't need the extra complication of NSIS at this time.
I am using VS2019

Comment: Does the `PACKAGE` project not show up in your Solution Explorer menu? It is often grouped with the other CMake predefined targets (e.g. `INSTALL`, `ZERO_CHECK`, etc.)

Comment: There are no predefined targets at all in Solution Explorer. Perhaps I need to configure something?

Comment: Just tried adding the following based on your clue - no effect:
 
     set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
     set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER "CMake")

Comment: Are you using VS folders? (`set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)`) It is possible that the predefined targets are in a collapsed folder. Without knowing the *specifics* of how you generated the solution file, it is difficult to say why these pre-defined CMake projects are not showing in your Solution Explorer. There is even a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069493/is-it-possible-not-to-generate-all-build-project-in-cmake) for how to get rid of them, because they are almost **always** available.

Comment: I'm letting cmake generate the solution file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with is you can't - at least not directly. Someone more enlightened may know better because it does indeed seem a strange oversight.

If you open a commmand prompt from tools/developer command prompt
you can run cpack manually from there.

Another important point is that CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX should not be set on Windows. 
See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17534

You can improve on this by adding a custom target (or targets) to your *CMakeLists.txt* which will be visible in the [targets view](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-targets-view-single-file-compilation-and-cache-generation-settings/).
For example (base on https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2017-January/064830.html) add:

```
SET( CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BundleConfig.cmake" )
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( bundle
         COMMAND "${CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND}"
                 "-C" "$<CONFIGURATION>"
            "--config" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BundleConfig.cmake"
            COMMENT "Running CPack. Please wait..."
            DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME} doxygen)
```

Doxygen documentation to be included in the install package is an extra dependency in my case.

Comment: Accepting my own answer until/unless someone comes up with a better one.

Comment: This may not be helpful at this point, but the linked question uses the "old" way of using cmake with windows: run cmake to create visual studio solution file, then open that file in visual studio. 

From your references to cmake integration, I assume you use the new cmake integration with "open folder", which does not create solution or project(.vcxproj) files for visual studio (per default, it uses Ninja as a build-system instead of msbuild). 

So if you generate the solution the traditional way, you should still get the PACKAGE.vcxproj

Comment: Its helpful to know that there even was an old and a new way.